# Using HTTPS with AsyncHttpClient(Library)

Tags: android, rest, https, android-asynctask

I want to request to HTTPS servers without bypassing SSL certificate validation by using,

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
```

I want a the method that uses the keystore file for verifying the SSL. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: First Download the **Keystore Explorer** [Download Link](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) and create a new Keystore file of type **BKS-V1** and import your **public key certificate** to the keystore.

Step 2: Copy the Keystore file to res/raw of your project.

Step 3: Use this function to get the SSLSocketFactory

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = null;
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            InputStream instream = this.getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.raw.website_public);
            keyStore.load(instream, "keystore_password".toCharArray());
            sslFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslFactory;
    }
```

Step 4 : Set SocketFactory in AsyncHttpClient object.

```
        AsyncHttpClient mAsyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        mAsyncHttpClient.addHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        mAsyncHttpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: I have followed your solution to make an https request with asynchttpclientlibrary. what is the best way to store keystore password in android app? is it safe to store on Android has it can be decrypted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could ref this [library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/package-summary.html).The AsyncHttpClient in the library can be used to make asynchronous GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP requests in your Android applications.And also supply SSlSocketFactory to specify SSL related parameters.